# Contravariant why Foo[C] is a subtype of Foo[B]?

Tags: scala, contravariance

I am trying to understand variance and in the book that I bought it explains as follow:

> • A type with an unannotated parameter Foo[A] is invariant in A. This 
>   means there is no relationship between Foo[B] and Foo[C] no matter
>   what the sub- or super-type relationship is between B and C.
>
> • A type with a parameter Foo[+A] is covariant in A. If C is a
>   subtype of B, Foo[C] is a subtype of Foo[B].
>
> • A type with a parameter Foo[-A] is contravariant in A. If C is a
>   supertype of B, Foo[C] is a subtype of Foo[B].

I have trouble to understand this sentence:

```
If C is a supertype of B, Foo[C] is a subtype of Foo[B].
```

Why not:

```
Foo[C] is a supertype of Foo[B].
```

`C` is a supertype `B` but why `C` change suddenly to subtype of `B` in contravariant?

Comment: Because that is how contravariance is defined. If `Foo[C]` is a supertype of `Foo[B]`, as you propose, then it would have been covariant.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> `C` is a supertype `B` but why `C` change suddenly to subtype of `B` in
>   contravariant?

That is the definition of contravariance, it *reverses* the relation order (in our case, the "is subtype of" relation `<:`). 
Notice that it is not that `C` is now a subtype of `B`, that relationship is fixed, it is *the thing that is a container of* `C`, i.e. `Foo[C]`, is now a subtype of the container of `B`, `Foo[B]`, not directly `B` itself.

The classic example for contravariance is function objects. Functions in Scala are contravariant in their argument type and covariant in their return type, i.e. `Function1[-T, +R]`.

Lets see an example. Assume we have a small ADT:

```
sealed trait Animal
case class Mouse() extends Animal
case class Lion() extends Animal
```

And now we want to create a function from `Lion => String`. Can we feed it a concrete function from `Animal => String`?

```
def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
  val animalToString: (Animal) => String = an => an.toString
  val lionToString: (Lion) => String = animalToString

  lionToString(new Lion())
}
```

Why does this compile? Because when you invoke `lionToString` with a `Lion`, you know for sure that it'll be able to invoke any function defined on `Animal`, because `Lion <: Animal`. But the other way around isn't true. Assume `Function1` was covariant in its argument type:

```
def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
  val lionToString: (Lion) => String = an => an.toString
  val animalToString: (Animal) => String = lionToString

  lionToString(new Mouse()) // <-- This would blow up.
}
```

Then we'd be able to pass a different subtype of `Animal` when our function actually expects a `Lion`.